# An inequality related to the numbers of faces of polytopes with d+2 facets

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, inequalities, convex-polytopes, binomial-coefficients

I would like to prove an inequality related to the number of $k$-faces of two $d$-polytopes with $d+2$ facets; see (1) below.

Let $r>0$, $s>0$, $t\ge 0$, and $d\ge 2$ be such that $d=r+s+t$. We denote by $\Delta({r,s})$ the sum of an $r$-dimensional simplex and an $s$-dimensional simplex with $r,s>0$, lying in complementary subspaces. The polytope $\Delta(r,s)$ is a simple polytope of dimension $r+s$. A $d$-dimensional $P$ polytope with $d+2$ facets is a $t$-fold pyramid over $\Delta({r,s})$. The number $f_k$ of its $k$-dimensional faces is as follows.

$$f_k(P)= \binom{r+s+t+2}{k+2} -\binom{s+t+1}{k+2}-\binom{r+t+1}{k+2} +\binom{t+1}{k+2}.$$

I am interested in finding the $d$-polytopes with $d+2$ facets, $2d+1$ vertices, and  a smallest number of faces. Having $2d+1$ vertices amounts to saying that $d=rs$.

Let $r_{2}>r_{1}>0$ and  $s_{1}>s_{2}>0$ be such that $r_{i}\le s_{i}$ for $i=1,2$. And let $t_{1},t_{2}\ge 0$ and $d\ge 2$ be such that $d=r_{i}+s_{i}+t_{i}$ and $d=r_{i}s_{i}$ for $i=1,2$. Suppose that $P_{i}$ be a $t_{i}$-fold pyramid over $\Delta({r_{i},s_{i}})$. Experimentation has shown that

\begin{equation}
(1)\quad f_{k}(P_{1})< f_{k}(P_{2})\quad \text{for each $k\in [2,d-2].$}
\end{equation}

Is (1) known?  I have  tried unsuccessfully to prove (1) for every possible triple $(r,s,t)$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you, and regards,
Guillermo